# Why does the log of supervisor keep reporting abnormal startup of Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.1?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

In Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.1, is ithe supervisor cannot be used to manage the database progress? After the supervisor is turned on, the log in the supervisor keeps reporting that IoTDB is starting repeatedly, but in fact IoTDB has been started only once and can be normally used. There is no such problem after switching to Version 0.13.4. What may be the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update to Version 1.2.1 of Apache IoTDB, to see if your problem has been solved.